# Infinitely Many Non-Sierpinski Numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is said that there are infinitely many odd $k$ that yield composite numbers of the form $k2^n+1$ for all $n$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number). These are called Sierpinski numbers.

My question is whether it is known that there are infinitely many $k$ that yield at least one prime number of the form $k2^n+1$ for some $n$. If so, are there any classes of numbers that we know for sure are not Sierpinski numbers (without having to brute-force verify that there is a prime in the sequence like we did with 10223).

Comment: Select $n=1$ and the numbers $2k+1$ include all odd primes, so there are infinitely many of them, hence infinitely many $k$.

Comment: $k$ must be odd for Sierpinski numbers, so $2k+1$ does not include all odd primes.

Comment: There are also infinitely many primes of the form $4r-1$ for $r$ and integer, and his is easy to show.